# What is the proper way of accessing static fields in Java?

Tags: java, class, variables, static

I just started learning Java and I wrote a class to test using static fields. Everything works fine but in Eclipse I see an icon which when hovered comes out as: "The static method getCounter from the type CarCounter should be **accessed in a static way**." What's the right way then?

Here's the class:

```
public class CarCounter {
    static int counter = 0;

    public CarCounter(){
        counter++;
    }

    public static int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }
}
```

And here's where I try to access variable counter:

```
public class CarCounterTest {
    public static void main( String args[] ){
        CarCounter a = new CarCounter();
        System.out.println(a.getCounter()); //This is where the icon is marked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Static fields and methods are not belong to a specific object, but to a class, so you should  access them from the class, and not from an object:

```
CarCounter.getCounter()
```

and not

```
a.getCounter()
```

Comment: replace *need* by *should* as both lines of code are correct but the second one is discouraged

Comment: This answered it for me; your answer was short at the same time concise. Amazing!

Comment: @Binyamin Sharet I know this was an older question but your comment helped me through my project. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Use `CarCounter.getCounter()`. That makes it clear that it's nothing to do with the object that the `a` variable's value refers to - the counter is associated with the type itself, rather than any specific instance of the type.

Here's an example of why it's really important:

```
Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
t.start();
t.sleep(1000);
```

What does it *look* like that code is doing? It looks like it's starting a new thread and then "pausing" it somehow - sending it to sleep for a second.

In fact, it's starting a new thread and pausing the *current* thread, because `Thread.sleep` is a static method which *always* makes the current thread sleep. It *can't* make any other thread sleep. That's a lot clearer when it's explicit:

```
Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
t.start();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Basically, the ability of the first snippet of code to compile is a mistake on the part of the language designers :(

Comment: c# designers fixed this mistake.

Answer (score 9):

That would be:

```
System.out.println(CarCounter.getCounter());
```

Answer (score 2):

It is even possible, though highly discouraged, to write:

```
Math m = null;
double d = m.sin(m.PI/4.0);
System.out.println("This should be close to 0.5 " + (d*d));
```

This is because static accesses look at the declared type of the variable, and never actually dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

Static elements belong to the class. Therefore, the best way to access them is via the class. 
So in your case, the print out should be.

```
System.out.println(CarCounter.getCounter());
```

This may feel triviaval unnecessary but it is not.
Consider the following code

```
// VehicleCounter.java
public class VehicleCounter {
    static int counter = 0;

    public VehicleCounter(){
        counter++;
    }

    public static int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }
}
// CarCounter.java
public class CarCounter extends VehicleCounter {
    static int counter = 0;

    public CarCounter(){
        counter++;
    }

    public static int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }
}
// CarCounterTest.java
public class CarCounterTest {
    public static void main( String args[] ){
        VehicleCounter vehicle1 = new VehicleCounter();
        VehicleCounter vehicle2 = new CarCounter();
        System.out.println(vehicle1.getCounter());
        System.out.println(vehicle2.getCounter());
    }
}
```

What should the above code prints?

The behaviour of the above code is hard to define. `vehicle1` is declared as `VehicleCounter` and the object is actually a `VehicleCounter` so it should print 2 (two vehicles are created).

`vehicle2` is declared as `VehicleCounter` but the object is actuall `CarCounter`. Which should be printed?

I really don't know what will be printed but I can see that it can easily be confused. So for a better practice the static elements should always be accessed via the class it defined.

It much easier to predict what to be printed by the following code.

```
// CarCounterTest.java
public class CarCounterTest {
    public static void main( String args[] ){
        VehicleCounter vehicle1 = new VehicleCounter();
        VehicleCounter vehicle2 = new CarCounter();
        System.out.println(VehicleCounter.getCounter());
        System.out.println(CarCounter    .getCounter());
    }
}
```

Hope this explains.

NawaMan :-D

Answer (score 0):

Static members should be accessed statically, i.e., ClassName.memberName.
Non-static access is allowed though (objectName.memberName) but is discouraged.