# how to implement static list of objects in java

Tags: java, list

just want to ask if the class i created below is correct or if something is wrong because of the use of static list of objects and if my implementation of encapsulation in correct because i need to limit the access to my static variable.

```
public class Car {
    private String carName, carPlateNumber;
    private static List<Car> carList;

    public Car(String carName, String carPlateNumber) {
        super();
        this.carName = carName;
        this.carPlateNumber = carPlateNumber;
    }

    public String getCarName() {
        return carName;
    }

    public void setCarName(String carName) {
        this.carName = carName;
    }

    public String getCarPlateNumber() {
        return carPlateNumber;
    }

    public void setCarPlateNumber(String carPlateNumber) {
        this.carPlateNumber = carPlateNumber;
    }

    public static void createCarList() {
        carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    }

    public static void addCarToList(Car car) {
        carList.add(car);
    }

    public static Car getCarAt(int location) {
        return carList.get(location);
    }

    public static void clearCarList() {
        carList.clear();
    }

    public static List<Car> getCarList() {
         return carList;
    }
}
```

and then to use this class like this

```
Car.createCarList();
Car.addCarToList(new Car("Mustang","CA-12343"));
. . .
. . .
```

and so on....

Comment: Why is it in `Car`?  Feels weird that the bean you're using has a cache of itself and its other instances.

Comment: Why not use an `enum` instead?

Comment: Can you give me another example to implement it properly?? because i'm confuse of how can i have one instance of list of cars for other class to use.

Comment: you must separate you bean fields and caching, bean must consist of its element Car (platnumber , model , name, etc ) list of cars should be / somehow must be in the main. plus if you are using static fields, theres no need to encapsulate it (getter/setter) you should access it directly,

Comment: @agbinfo can you please elaborate on what you mean by "Why not use an `enum` instead?" How and why would you use an `enum`?

Comment: i have edited my question base on what you have suggested? if there something i miss let me know.

Comment: @niczm25 I've added an example of how to use `enum` but you can search for `enum singleton in java` to get more info.

Answer (score 4):

Something like the example below could be used to share your list.

The advantages of using an `enum` is that it provides for lazy initialization; The instance is not created until you need it. Also, when it does get initialized, it is done in a thread-safe way. You could get the same result with a class but then you'd need to synchronize the initialization some other way to make the list thread safe.

There are other ways to pass a list but when the list is global, I think that this singleton pattern is an easy and safe way to do so.

Creating the list in the `main` method makes it harder to reuse the list in another program. For example, if you have several lists, then you'd need to create all of them in the `main` method then pass them as arguments in every call or. If you have other classes refer to the `Main` class to access the list, as suggested elsewhere, then you create circular dependencies. The application shouldn't need to know how to create the lists required by its libraries and the libraries shouldn't need to know about the application.

```
public enum Cars {
  theCars;

  /* Class can be defined in a different file or defined here. 
     For example:
  public static class Car {
    public String name;
    public String make;
  }

  */

  private List<Car> cars;
  Cars() {
    cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    cars.add(...)
  }

  // ... functions to deal with Cars
  // or simply return the entire list
  public List<Car> getList() {
    return cars;
  }
}
```

You can then get the cars by refering to `Cars.theCars.getList()`

Comment: Please notice that the constructor for an enum type must be package-private or private access. It automatically creates the constants that are defined at the beginning of the enum body. You cannot invoke an enum constructor yourself. also you can not refer to the enum inside the initializer!!!! so in this case `cars.add(...)` is wrong. Also please fix your naming, the emum is called `Cars` and you are creating the list of `Cars`. I am assuming this is a mistake otherwise it would not make any sense at all.

Comment: @Arsham Have you tried the code above? It works fine. `Cars` is an enum. `Cars.theCars` is an instance of `Cars` - the only one defined. The class `Car` is a regular class and is not defined here. The first time that `theCars` is referenced it is initialized (lazy initialization) so as soon as it is referenced, the constructor is called and you can use `Cars.theCars.getList()` to add, remove, or otherwise access the `List<Car>`

Comment: @agbinfo what is the advantage of doing this? i.e. why on earth would you do this? this defeats the purpose of `Enum` which is:  "An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants."  If you have a class you can create **any** objects as long as the values you supply to the constructor are valid then why would you use `enum`?

Answer (score 2):

your bean must consist of the following element

```
public class Car{
   String name,platenumber,model, etc......

   //getters and setters

}
```

for caching purposes you can put it in your main class.

```
public class Main{

    public static List<Car> carList;

  public static void main(String[] args){

     //do what you want to do here
  }

}

public class OtherClassAccessCarList{

  public void someMethod(){
    //how to access static field properly
    Main.carList.add(new Car());
  }

}
```

ref: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562321/what-is-the-proper-way-of-accessing-static-fields-in-java)    [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537443/java-accessing-static-method-properly)

Comment: what is the difference between what you did and what he did in his code, the objective (I assume) is to keep list of all the objects create of type `Car`, why would you take out the static list and create 3 classes when you can have one. In his original implementation every time an object of type `Car` is built he can add it to the list if he wants. I can see what you mean by separating the list from Object definition but if someone want to cash all the created objects then he will use a proper cash. Also, now every time I need to add a `Car` to the list I need to remember where the list is.

Comment: ah, because initially he suggested it without example, so i've edited my question base what he suggested...

Comment: @niczm25 what I am trying to say is your initial implementation was fine. I agree with him saying you don't need as setter for the list and since the list was private, getter was appropriate. The current one is also fine, except now you made the list public so everyone can access the list, that is fine if you dont mind that. If your code base is not big and you want to do bunch of stuff in main and keep track of cars there it is fine. If your code base is big and you will add to this list from different classes I would keep it in `Car`

Comment: @Arsham what do mean?? my first implementation is somehow correct, or is there any better way to implement it??

Comment: @niczm25 If you put the list in `Main` then you get circular dependencies. `Main` depends on the classes it calls and these classes depend on `Main`. This means that the sub-classes are not reusable without `Main` and it should be avoided.

Comment: @Arsham i would like to address what you said `Also, now every time I need to add a Car to the list I need to remember where the list is.` i think you will always remember where you put your static list? if you access the list outside the Car class you need to remember the list is in the Car class right? it is the same as putting it in the main right? I give 3 classes as an example of how to use/ can he/she access the static fields outside the class.

Comment: @niczm25 why do you think your first implementation was wrong? I dont think it was wrong. As, was it is a best practice? that depends on your requirement.
@Kerppag yes I agree you would remember where you put the list but also remember you don't always write programs with "main" method in them. If there is one Yes absolutely keep track of all the `Car` objects in a list there. That is fine.

Comment: @Arsham because i get negative votes, and how come i gain negative votes for a question where i'm just confuse if my implementation was right or wrong? but by the way thanks for your suggestion and all of the answer i get for this question, i learn something new from this. never the less it makes me feel like i don't want to ask question again because its hard to gain points and just by posting this question i got 3 negative votes immediately.

Comment: I THINK,it is possible you got negative vote because either the question is too simple and/or the response to it can be found with a little research. Doesnt have to do anything with your implementation.

Comment: i agree with @Arsham some of users here thinks that the question is too simple and easy to search in google or with the use of some documentation.

Comment: ok, got it, next time i try my best to find answer first, but the thing is i ask this question is because i've tried searching and i've already read some documentation about class and objects and use of static, no luck on finding such of @Arsham answer. how to properly use static list where i can limit the methods it can use by making it private and just use static methods for the methods i just want other can do. initially i'm confuse if i can use 'List<Car>' inside the 'Car' class or if it is ok to use it.

Comment: 1)If you google "how to keep track of objects in java" you will see plenty of discussions on this issue. 
2) Yes you can use `List <Car>` inside of the class `Car` there is no problem with that. You should have probably rephrased your question as : hey this is how I did it and it works, how else can this be done and what are cons and pros of your method. That would be a better question.

Comment: ah, thats how it suppose to be, next time i will try, to find the right key word to search properly. btw, many thanks (bow).